# Don't show products in the new products block if the price is set to 0

Tags: module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Is there any way to stop showing new products if the price is set to 0? I am reffering to the block new products module. I tried to add something like:

`{if $newproduct.price != 0}`

in blocknewproducts.tpl but it didn't work for me.

Comment: In what template do you put the line of is a new product?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the template of the block new products that you see it is in the folder ***themes/modules/blocknewproducts/blocknewproducts.tpl*** not in the folder of the original module.

Inside the template there a line like this :

```php
{foreach from=$new_products item=newproduct name=myLoop}
     <!-- You could put something line this just before to put the product -->
     {if $newproduct.price != 0}

     {/if}
{/foreach}
```

With the above line only show the products with price not zero. I hope this help you.

Comment: well, that's exactly how i did it and nothing happened, but here's the strange thing (what I just did): i'm forcing compilation, cache and CCC are off and i deleted everything between the foreach statement and it still works like nothing happened :O... and yes, i did it both in the themes folder and in the root folder... this is really strange now...

Comment: srry, solved it... i modified the module so i can add it to the homeTabContent and that's why it didn't work. i had to build a new file called "newproduct-list.tpl" and link that to the hook. Thank you for your help and have a nice day :)